# JQuery Datatables only showing 10 rows and 1 page and buttons are disabled previous and next

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, datatables

I am using jquery datatables to display customer data. I am using serverside processing. However I am a little confused on how to use the recordsFilteredProperty. When i set it to the total count of the customers table everything shows ok, but when i scroll to page 2 there is no data which is expected. However if i change recordsFiltered to result.Count then i get showing 1 of 10 and there is only one page showing for pagination and the previous and next buttons are disabled.

Here is my MVC code:

```cs
public IActionResult GetCustomers(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
{
    var totalCount = DatabaseLogic.GetCustomersCount();
    var filteredCount = totalCount;

    string sortBy = "";
    string sortDir = "";

    if (model.order != null)
    {
        sortBy = model.columns[model.order[0].column].data;
        sortDir = model.order[0].dir.ToLower();
    }
    
    totalCount = DatabaseLogic.GetCustomersCount();

    var search = model?.search?.value == "" ? "" :  model?.search?.value;

    int startRec = model.start;
    int pageSize = model.length;

    var result = DatabaseLogic.GetCustomers(startRec, pageSize, search, sortBy, sortDir);


    return Json(new { draw = model.draw, recordsTotal = totalCount, recordsFiltered = filteredCount, data = result });
}
```

Datatables screenshot:

[image: Datatables Screen Shot]

Comment: In case this provides a quick answer, have you seen the definitions of `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` in the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data)? Does that resolve the question? These, together with the [sent parameter](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) values for `start` and `length`, are used to build the paging info and controls you see. If that still is not clear, perhaps a more detailed example may help you.

Comment: yes thanks. But heres the problem, I am passing start and length into a query to return just those records for that page, so i have to have a second query to return the number of rows after filtering?

Comment: That is one way. If you are performing your filtering and paging combined into one (database?) operation, then you won't know the total number of filtered records. The way I have done this is to only filter (and sort) from the database - and then take the required slice from the app server's result set, as per the paging requirements. Depending on your data volumes this may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: I am lost here, i have done a seperate query to return the filtered rows minus - paging and there is still just one paging item and the previous and next buttons are disabled

Comment: Separate steps are: (1) Get a result set from the database. This contains all of the data matching the requested filter, and the requested sort order. Step (2): In my application layer, I then process this result set to extract the specific n rows which need to be sent to DataTables (for example, the 10 rows for page 3). Because I do this, I know from step (1) how many filtered records I have. I still need to check (separately) the _total_ number of records, of course.

Comment: an example would be greatly appreciated but your information has been helpful thanks

Comment: I did it wrong, got it working thank you very much for helping me understand a confusing topic

Comment: Glad you got it. You are welcome to add your own answer to the question if you think it may help someone in the future. You can even accept your answer, if you wish.

Comment: No you go ahead, you answered it

Answer (score 2):

When using DataTables server-side processing, there are a few points to consider to handle paging controls and the table information summary correctly. The following describes one basic approach.

By "paging controls" I am referring to the "First", Previous", "Next", "Last" and page number buttons. How these are displayed is [configurable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) - but here I will assume the default `simple_numbers` option.

By "table information summary" I am referring to text such as the following:

```
Showing 21 to 30 of 57 entries
```

And the equivalent text if a filter is applied:

```
Showing 1 to 10 of 21 entries (filtered from 57 total entries)
```

These messages are also configurable using [language.info](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.info) and [language.infoFiltered](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.infoFiltered).

---

There are 4 server-side processing values which control the above behavior:

In the parameters [sent from DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) to the server:

- `start` - the (zero-based) index of the first record to be displayed in the table.
- `length` - the total number of records which can be displayed in one page, which is typically controlled by the length-changer drop down.

In the parameters sent from the server to DataTables (along with our ten records to be displayed):

- `recordsTotal` - the total number of records in the unfiltered data set (for example, this may be the row count of the source database table).
- `recordsFiltered` - the number of records in the source data set, after any filters have been applied. The filters are those provided in the DataTables search input field. If there are no filters, or if the filters do not affect any rows, then this value will equal `recordsTotal`.

So, if `start` = 20 and `length` = 10, this means we want DataTables to display rows 21 through 30 from our overall data set (i.e. page two). Therefore the server will send this specific set of ten records back to DataTables, to be displayed.

And if `recordsTotal` = 123, but after filtering there are only 77 relevant records, then `recordsFiltered` = 77.

---

However, in order to use the above data effectively, the server must also take into account any column ordering settings in DataTables. This information is also included in the [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) data, using the `order[i][column]` fields.

The server must therefore build a result set which is filtered and sorted as requested.

The number of records in this result set is the `recordsFiltered` value.

The fact that the result set is sorted, allows the server to select the correct subset of display data from the result set, as specified by the `start` and `length` values. It is this specific slice of data which is returned in the JSON response from the server to DataTables.

(This is also the reason DataTables can handle millions of records, when using server-side processing: It only receives one small subset of the overall data, for each rendering/drawing.)

---

This leaves one gap: What is the `recordsTotal` value? How you determine this depends on the specific server-side implementation process.

One approach could be as follows:

1. The server builds a SQL select statement to retrieve the sorted and filtered data.
2. The application server layer extracts the required subset of display data.

In this case, the application server needs to issue a second SQL statement to count the total number of unfiltered records. This gives us the `recordsTotal` value.

There may be alternative implementation approaches, if the "two queries" approach is not practical. However, the above approach will ensure pagination and information features behave as expected.

Comment: i have one more question. I have to get the count of filtered rows, which requires another call to the database. Even if I included it in the procedure surely slows it down when the dataset becomes large?
Does this slow down actually make it worse or better?
I am talking all serverside now, not client side, i understand you have to get the filter rows back for datatables, but surely two calls or one call with two querys or even an out parameter slows it down more than just once call then let linq do the rest? for example i have a query to get 5 rows then a query to count all filtered rows?

Comment: I am talking about the default view or even a few you filter, its two calls to the database no matter what, so you can paginate in the database procedure all you want, but you still have to do another query to get the count of filtered records. If i have 5 million rows and i filter down to 10000 then have a procedure when uses pagination thats fine, but i have to have another query that gets the count of the filtered rows which is 10000. @andrewjames

Comment: Understood. If your server-side approach is to only return the 10 paginated rows from the DB that will be displayed to the user, then, yes, you have to do extra (and possibly repetitious) work to count the "total in filter" number. That is one of the trade-offs you make when you choose how to implement server-side processing. My approach has been to assume the filtering is the most expensive step - which is why in my final section of the answer I retrieve all 10,000 filtered records, even if I only display 10 (and the extra "grand total" count is a fast query).

Comment: Whatever your approach, your DB needs to be well-tuned to support your filter queries, of course. And you may need to consider the risks of very wide user-provided filter criteria, which basically select "everything"...

Comment: ok thanks. I am mainly talking about the default view so all records returned at first, can you approximate at what record count things would slow down and by how much?

Comment: That depends on too many factors, which are specific to your environment... There is no way I could give you any meaningful advice.